# Remove comments from HTML and js in Google App Engine or Jinja2

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-platform, pagespeed

Now that pagespeed is going away in Google App Engine is there another simple way to remove comments in html & javascript. Thanks!

Current settings:

- pagespeed:

  - RemoveComments  # This one is critical
  - CollapseWhitespace
  - MinifyCss
  - JsOptimize

FYI: I'm using Python & jinja2 templates

Comment: I guess there are a lot of possible answers.. You didn't specify the language/platform/framework you want it to work in. Personally I'm looking for such solution in jinja2 templates.

Comment: jinja2 option to render or not would be great